# How to use https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift library?

Tags: swift, datepicker

I am creating a Swift iOS app in which I have to show a datepicker which accepts Month and Year. I have found one library at GitHub which looks the solution of my problem but I am not getting how to use it. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Link : https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift

Comment: have you run this in Swift 2.0? Because I'm getting some issues.

Comment: I am not getting any errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    let expiryDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView(frame: CGRectZero)
    yourtextField.inputView = expiryDatePicker
```

Comment: @ChetanPurohit: What did you do for select action? I get the picker now, after looking at kalim's answer. But stuck with selection

Answer (score 1):

Add the swift class https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift/master/MonthYearPickerView.swift file to your xcode project.

Comment: Yes..
I have added that .swift file to my project and set MonthYearPickerView as subclass for UIPickerView.. 
Added the given code as well..
It is throwing this error :
    fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/developer/MonthYearView/MonthYearView/MonthYearPickerView.swift, line 52